# Delete part of string value

Tags: c#

I want to mix 2 string in 1 randomly using foreach but I don't know how I delete the part I used on the string for the foreach like:

```
string s = "idontknow";
string sNew = "";
foreach(char ss in s){
    s = s + ss;
    ss.Delete(s); //don't exist
}
```

Full code here i'm trying to do:

```
            do
        {
            if (state == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; random.Next(1, 5) > variable.Length; i++)
                {
                    foreach (char ch in variable)
                    {
                        fullString = fullString + ch;
                    }
                }
                state++;
            }
            else if (state == 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; random.Next(1, 5) > numbers.Length; i++)
                {
                    foreach (char n in numbers)
                    {
                        fullString = fullString + n;
                    }
                }
                state--;
            }
        } while (variable.Length != 0 && numbers.Length != 0);
```

Comment: Can you share some sample input and output?

Comment: What do mean by delete the string?

Comment: Chetan, everytime i use foreach so the first letter of the string, i want to delete it. And for input or out i do a example

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident, that in your first code snippet, you are creating an infinite loop, since you are appending the used char back to the string while removing it from the first position.

Regarding your specification to shuffle two stings together, this code sample might do the job:

```cs
public static string ShuffleStrings(string s1, string s2){
    List<char> charPool = new();
    foreach (char c in s1) {
        charPool.Add(c);
    }
    foreach (char c in s2) {
        charPool.Add(c);
    }
    Random rand = new();
    char[] output = new char[charPool.Count];
    for(int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++) {
        int randomIndex = rand.Next(0, charPool.Count);
        output[i] = charPool[randomIndex];
        charPool.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
    }
    return new string(output);
}
```

In case you just want to shuffle one string into another string, just use an empty string as the first or second parameter.

Example:

```cs
string shuffled = ShuffleStrings("TEST", "string");
Console.WriteLine(shuffled);

// Output:
// EgsTtSnrTi
```

There are possibly other solutions, which are much shorter, but I think this code is pretty easy to read and understand.

Concerning the performance, the code above should works both for small stings and large strings.
Since strings are immutable, each modify-operation on any string, e.g. `"te" + "st"` or `"test".Replace("t", "")`, will allocate and create a new string in the memory, which is - in a large scale - pretty bad.
For that very reason, I initialized a `char` array, which will then be filled.
Alternatively, you can use:

```cs
using System.Text;

StringBuilder sb = new();
// append each randomly picked char
sb.Append(c);

// Create a string from appended chars
sb.ToString();
```

And if your question was just how to remove the first char of a string:

```
string myStr = "Test";
foreach (char c in myStr) {
    // do with c whatever you want
    myStr = myStr[1..]; // assign a substring exluding first char (start at index 1)
    Console.WriteLine($"c = {c}; myStr = {myStr}");
}

// Output:
// c = T; myStr = est
// c = e; myStr = st
// c = s; myStr = t
// c = t; myStr =
```

Comment: Hi, thanks to you for answer. I have 2 3 error fixable because i'm using 4.7 .net framework,  sorry for wasn't very clear with my question, i'm trying to do a personal obfuscator so i have 2 strings and i want to fuse it in one with many different functions. If you can do something for me here an example of functions i uses and what i imagine.                                   [var] WUP2T6G = '4'; [var] 9POLQ = 'D'; [var] RNT9 = '4'; [var] DVIPZ = '4'; 363\637\393\739\ [var] 8VVJHO1 = '7'; [var] 78GOE0 = '4'; 353\736\

Comment: First of all, these functions do look more of assigning variables. I have no idea what they are supposed to do. Secondly, you probably should read both "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)" and "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"